# How to automatically go to the next rows and Insert multiple rows using single insert commnad in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I already saw other post related to this question, but they did not solve my problem. I want to automatically go to next rows and want to insert that row in the table. I am transfering sample of data from another database. I want to insert large set of rows... Right now I am getting first row repeatedly in all rows. I need to go to to next rows automoatically

Below is my sample code...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (info1, info2, info3,...) " 
          ."VALUES (" . $row['info1'] . "," . $row['info2'] . "," . $row['info3'] . "),  
                   (" . $row['info1'] . "," . $row['info2'] . "," . $row['info3'] . "),  
                   (" . $row['info1'] . "," . $row['info2'] . "," . $row['info3'] . "),  
                   (" . $row['info1'] . "," . $row['info2'] . "," . $row['info3'] . ")";
}
```

Comment: Are you inserting data that you selected from the same database?
In that case, you may not need to use php but can do it in one query: insert into dest_table (field1, field2, field3) select field1, field2, field3 from source_table

Comment: No. I am inserting from different db.

Comment: what about this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Tush - what exactly are you trying to auto-increment (which column)? Also, is there any reason not to simply make this column an auto-increment one and to insert data into the other columns(only), resulting in the target column having a value that increases with each row?

Comment: if you insert NULL into a auto increment field, it will set it to the next value

Comment: @enhzflep - These rows in the table should automatically increase. so that i can insert all rows automatically. I don't want to disturb old table auto increament(AI).

Comment: @verhie - I just want to insert rows automatically.. i am new to this program

Comment: @Tush - are you saying that _all_ fields in the new database should be different (larger) than they were in the original database?

Comment: NO, they are same.

Comment: @Tush - I asked you for the column name and you ignored the question. You then said "I just want to insert rows automatically.. i am new to this program" - not helpful. You've used "autoincrement", which is a word with an agreed meaning, yet, apparently eschewed this, opting for your own one. It would be to your benefit to edit the question such that it include a small sample of data in the original table and the same data after inserted into the new table. Terminology and the classic X/Y problem will no longer be a problem then. Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated. [continued]

Comment: okay. i did. sorry for confusion

Comment: @Tush - and you should no longer use them, they will be (have been?) dropped from language. You should look into PDO or mysqli (I reccomend PDO). This will (0) solve the deprecation issue, (1) allow you to use what are known as 'prepared statements' - these have several benefits, the primary ones being (a) automatic escaping of entered data (read: http://bobby-tables.com/) (b) the ability to perform the same query repeatedly with different data - as you need to do in order to copy the rows 1-by-1. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp and https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Thank you. will try

Answer (score 0):

This sql Query could help you. You can insert the select datas in one Query. See MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
    (info1, info2, info3)
SELECT 
    source_table.info1,
    source_table.info2,
    source_table.info3, 
FROM 
    source_table 
WHERE 
    (WHERE CLAUSE)
```

Comment: Thanks but I have 2 different database and its large number of data. I really want to do, as i mentioned in sample code. I am only missing with auto increament of rows

Answer (score 0):

do a separate insert for each selected rows:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (incremented_field, info1, info2, info3) " 
      ."VALUES (NULL, " . $row['info1'] . "," . $row['info2'] . "," . $row['info3'] . ")";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```